# counting iterations in recursion python

Tags: python, recursion, iteration

I saw the thread about how to keep count in a recursive function but I didn't quite follow the answer and it also didn't seem to apply to what I am looking for (at least from what I could tell so sorry if this is a repetitive question!). I am working on a piece of code to decipher text that has been Ceasar shifted in several different spots. I have constructed a recursive function that works well to shift the text until until it has found the correct shift and to return the shifted text but I am unable to get the function to return the number of times it iterated.

```
text_to_shift = apply_coder(text[start:], build_decoder(1))
Ltext = text_to_shift.split()

for w in Ltext:
    if is_word(wordlist, w) == True:
        text = ' '.join(Ltext)
        return text
    else:
        text = ' '.join(Ltext)
        return find_best_shifts_rec(wordlist, text, start)
```

I could write this as a while loop but I like the elegance of what I have written. I am leaning towards a global variable (which I'm going to try after this) but I feel there is a better solution. Thank you in advance for either an answer or a better explanation of the one in the thread i referred to.

Comment: This is not your whole function. We're missing at least the first line, the one starting with `def`. (Also, "elegance" and "leaning towards a global variable" do not belong in the same post.)

Comment: A cheap and nasty way that often works well enough is to look at the stack depth.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add in the header for the function is: def find_best_shifts_rec(wordlist, text, start): and that apply_coder() and build_decoder() are functions I have previously written and work as I need them to. In short they shift the given text backwards 1 letter

Comment: @user2357 yah I realize global and elegant don't belong together lol, I was just going to try it for testing purposes

Comment: Note: Your function has a bug. It will never get past the first iteration of the `for` loop, as it always returns in the first iteration.

Comment: that's the beauty of it, it never needs to go farther than 1 iteration in the for loop. if the text starts with a word that exists in "wordlist" than I know that I have found the value for the first shift sequence and this function can be exited to be called again later with a different starting point in the string to be decoded. Otherwise it just shifts the text again until it finds a word. also, thank you for your detailed answer. I'm going to implement it in the morning :)

Comment: If you only want the first item, just use `Ltext[0]`. A `for` loop indicates to the reader that you want to do some looping. (Also, don't compare things to `True`. Just say `if is_word(wordlist, w):`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def recursive_thing(calls=1):
    # "calls" argument keeps track of recursion depth
    if keep_recursing():
        # pass a higher count to the recursive call
        recursive_thing(calls + 1)
    else:
        print calls
        return
```

Give your function an argument that keeps track of the recursion depth, or put the recursion in a helper function with such an argument.